# What is the cost breakdown of a Falcon Heavy launch?

Tags: spacex, falcon-heavy, cost

I don't know if this was already asked, but I'm very curious about the cost breakdown of a Falcon Heavy launch and what the difference is from Falcon 9's cost per launch. Would it be more or less per pound?

Comment: I doubt that they publish detailed cost breakdowns, but who knows.

Comment: Are you asking about a cost breakdown for SpaceX's customers, or a cost breakdown for SpaceX itself? If it's the latter, that apparently is extremely proprietary data. The people who know the answer to that question will lose their jobs, and possibly more, if divulged.

Comment: About SpaceX itself

Comment: I'm sure the price (to the customer) can be discovered to some extent but it is not that easy as there are so many ifs and buts concerning shared piggybacking mission options, different orbits and masses, expended or RTLS or ADSP modes ,special documentation, insurance requirements etc etc. as for the cost to SpaceX we can only guess.

Comment: Afaik from their actual pricing, an educated estimate could be made. Also the ordinary falcon9 launch prices could help (for example, stage2 is the same in them).